# Solve implicit equations, input and plot the solution in a different equation

Tags: plotting, implicit, parameters

I have two implicitly defined variables, $\sigma_D$ and $\sigma_M$ one of which is a function of the parameter $v$. In particular, 
$\sigma_D = F(\sigma_D,v)$ where $F(\sigma_D,v)=0$ if $ c_D < -0.1$, $F(\sigma_D,v)=\frac{c_D+0.1}{2.1}$ if $-0.1 \leq c_D \leq 2$ and $1$ for $c_D > 2$, and

$$
c_{D} =0.5((\frac{\sigma_D^2 + (1-\sigma_D)(2-\sigma_D)(.6)^2 }{\sigma_D^2 + (2-\sigma_D)^2 (.6)^2} - \frac{1-\sigma_D}{2-\sigma_D})(\sigma_D - (2-\sigma_D)(.6)^2)+1) -0.5v
$$

$$
\sigma_M = \frac{0.4}{2.1} \big[\frac{\sigma_M + .6(1-\sigma_M) }{\sigma_M + .6(1-\sigma_M) + 0.6} - \frac{1-\sigma_M}{2-\sigma_M}\big] + \frac{.1}{2.1}.
$$

I need to get the solutions for $v \in [0,5]$, then replace those values in the following two equations:
$$
V_{1} =  \frac{1}{2}(1+0.6\mu) + \frac{1}{2}[\sigma_M \mu + (1-\sigma_M)(1+ 0.6\mu )]
$$

$$
V_{2} = \frac{1}{4}(1+0.6\mu) + \frac{1}{4}[1 + 0.6\mu (\sigma_D  + (1-\sigma_D))] 2 + \frac{1}{4}[(1-\sigma_D)^2 (1+ 0.6\mu)) + 2 \sigma_D (1-\sigma_D)(1+\mu) + \sigma^{2}_D \mu]
$$

Finally, I need to plot both $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ on the same graph in the $\mu-v$ space with $\mu \in [0,5]$ and $v \in [0,5]$, or at least to produce a graph that shows when $V_2 > V_1$.

```
    c=2;
    e=0.1;
    f=0.6;
    gD=(sD^2 + (1 - sD) f^2 (2 - sD))/(sD^2 + f^2 (2 - sD)^2);
    XD=(1 - sD)/(2 - sD);
    cD = -0.5 v + 0.5 ((gD - XD) (sD - (2 - sD) f^2) + (2 - sD) (1 - XD));
    FD = Piecewise[{{0, cD <= -e}, {(cD + e)/(c + e), cD > -e && cD < c}, {1, 
    cD >= c}}];
    gM= (sM + (1 - sM) f)/(sM + (1 - sM) f + f);
    XM=(1 - sD)/(2 - sD);
    RHSM=(1 - f) (gM - XM);
    V1=.5(1+.6m) + .5(sM m + (1-sM)(1+.6m));
    V2-.25(1+.6m) + .5[1 + m(sD + .6(1-sD))] + .25[(1-sD)^2(1+.6m) + 2 sD (1-sD)(1+m) + sD^2 m ];
    Clear[e,c,f,gD,XD,cD,FD,gM,XM,RHSM];
```

I know how to get solutions for a particular value of v, but not how to input automatically the solution into $V_1$ and $V_2$ and then compare them in the $\mu - v$ space. Note also that $\sigma_M \in [0,1]$ and $\sigma_D \in [0,1]$.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: There is no definition of $\mu$.  Add this definition and write both functions $V_1, V_2$. $\sigma_M$  is it just a number (root of the equation)?

Comment: $\mu$ is merely a scalar and lies between 0 and 5. I have edited the above to reflect the change -- it is not a function. $v$ is also a scalar and lies between 0 and 5. Finally, yes, $\sigma_M$ is the root of the equation and does not depend on $v$.

Comment: This is strange. I got the roots of the equation from Mathematica, and they turn out to be $-2.90447$, $0.051765$ and $1.90033$. Although, I apologize for not being clear earlier that both $\sigma_D$ and  $\sigma_M$ should be between $0$ and $1$.

```
Format[s] := \[Sigma];
f = 0.6;
c = 2;
e = 0.1;
gR = (s + (1 - s) f)/(s + (1 - s) f + f);
X = (1 - s)/(2 - s); 
TM = (1 - f) (gR - X);
Solve[(TM + e)/(c + e) == s, s]
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, the roots are there `{{s -> -2.90447}, {s -> 0.051765}, {s -> 1.90033}}`. Need to take  0.051765? Can you add this to your message? And write down the expression for `V1,V2`.

Comment: Done! Let me know if there any further clarifications. Thanks a ton.

Comment: You cannot use function brackets `[ ]` as if they were parentheses `( )`

Comment: Oh! Yes. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code here (need to fix `[]` to `()` in `V2` as Bob suggested)

```
c = 2;
e = 0.1;
f = 0.6;
gD = (sD^2 + (1 - sD) f^2 (2 - sD))/(sD^2 + f^2 (2 - sD)^2);
XD = (1 - sD)/(2 - sD);
cD = -0.5 v + 0.5 ((gD - XD) (sD - (2 - sD) f^2) + (2 - sD) (1 - XD));
FD = Piecewise[{{0, cD <= -e}, {(cD + e)/(c + e), 
     cD > -e && cD < c}, {1, cD >= c}}];
gM = (sM + (1 - sM) f)/(sM + (1 - sM) f + f);
XM = (1 - sD)/(2 - sD);
RHSM = (1 - f) (gM - XM);
V1 = .5 (1 + .6 m) + .5 (sM m + (1 - sM) (1 + .6 m));
V2 = .25 (1 + .6 m) + .5 (1 + 
      m (sD + .6 (1 - sD))) + .25 ((1 - sD)^2 (1 + .6 m) + 
      2 sD (1 - sD) (1 + m) + sD^2 m);

sig = Table[{x, sD /. FindRoot[sD == FD /. v -> x, {sD, 1}]}, {x, 
    0, .5, .005}];

sigmaD = Interpolation[sig];

y = x /. NSolve[
   x == .4/2.1 ((x + (1 - x) .6)/(x + (1 - x) .6 + .6) - (1 - x)/(2 - 
           x)) + .1/2.1, x]
(*{-2.90447, 1.90033, 0.051765}*)
Plot3D[{V1 /. sM -> y[[3]], V2 /. sD -> sigmaD[v]}, {m, 0, .5}, {v, 
  0, .5}, PlotLegends -> {"V1", "V2"}, AxesLabel -> {"\[Mu]", "v"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. It works :)